# What function fits these criteria?

Tags: regression, distributions, poisson-distribution, curve-fitting

I want to use a function $f(x)$ to model my data $x$, where $x > 0$, and then fit the function's parameters to that data. My requirements are that $f(x)$ is continuous and smooth, $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, and there is a single peak in $f(x)$. Visually, this would look like a curve starting at $(0, 0)$, smoothly increasing to a peak, and then smoothly decreasing towards 0 as $x$ tends to infinity. This would look a bit like a Poisson distribution, but I want it to be continuous. What are some examples of functions that would satisfy this?

Comment: Gamma functions come to mind. You have two parameters to play with, which gives you some flexibility.

Comment: [This gallery of distributions](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366.htm) may be helpful.

Comment: Lots of options exist. $f(x)\propto x^2\exp(-bx),$ for example.